# Function reservation seats 3 dimension

Tags: c

I need to create a function that allows me to reserve places in a table. The table is 3-dimensional array.

`Tabblock[30][5][100]`

30 block; 5rank; 100 seats.

But a board like this is to bigger "segmentation fault". I try to make a struct like this:

```
  char tabbloc[33][5][10] = {} ;  
  int i = 0 ;
  int numblocares = 0 ; 

    for (i=0 ; i < 33 ; i++ )
    {
        for(i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
        {
            for (i = 0 ; i<100 ; i++)
            {
                tabbloc[i][i][i] = "libre" ; 
                printf("%s", tabbloc[i][i][i]); 

            }
        }
    }
```

But it didn't work. I cannot find a solution to reach the free seats and directly reserve the place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you actually want something as the follows:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char tabbloc[33][5][100] = {} ;  
    int numblocares = 0 ; 
    
    for (int x=0 ; x < 33 ; x++ )
    {
        for(int y = 0 ; y < 5 ; y++)
        {
            strcpy(tabbloc[x][y],"libre"); 
            printf("%s", tabbloc[x][y]); 
        }
    } 
   ... 
   return 0;
}
```

> 30 block; 5rank; 100 seats.

Change

```
char tabbloc[33][5][10] = {} ;
```

to

```
char tabbloc[33][5][100] = {} ;
```

You need to use different index variables in each loop signature, not the same `i` variable in all the loops.

Notice that with the given `tabbloc` structure (*i.e.,* `char tabbloc[33][5][100]`) you will have to use [strcpy](https://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/standard_library_functions/string_h/strcpy.php) to copy the string into the given position. And since `strcpy` has the signature:

```
char* strcpy(char* destination, const char* source);
```

You do not need the last loop you just pass the char* stored at `tabbloc[i][j];`